# UWP DependencyObject Binding Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: uwp, winui, dependencyobject

I have a Visual Studio 2019 UWP project with a XAML page using dependency properties for binding values. **It's all working fine in debug mode but not in release.** What's wrong with the way I am binding that VS relase doesn't like?

The sample code below shows a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.FontIcon with a binding to MyDependencyClass DependencyObject class.

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="{Binding ElementName=MyPageUI, Path=(local:myDependencyClass.myGlyph)}" />
```

The error is Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: 'XAML parsing failed.', and it is due to this binding in the FontIcon element. It does not matter the type of control, same error.

***{Binding ElementName=MyPageUI, Path=(local:myDependencyClass.myGlyph)}***

```
public abstract class MyDependencyClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyGlyphProperty;

    public static void SetMyGlyph(DependencyObject DepObject, string value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(MyGlyphProperty, value);
    }
    public static string GetMyGlyph(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (string)DepObject.GetValue(MyGlyphProperty);
    }

    static MyDependencyClass()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata("\xE72E");
        MyGlyphProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyGlyph",
                                                typeof(string),
                                                typeof(MyDependencyClass),
                                                MyPropertyMetadata);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's all working fine in debug mode but not in release.

I could reproduce your problem, and xaml binding code make sense, please feel free post your problem with windows feed back hub or post in [WinUI issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues) box. And currently we have a workaround that replace `Binding` with `x:Bind`, and use static property to replace Attached property.

**Xaml**

```
<FontIcon FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="{x:Bind local:TestClass.Glyph}" />
```

**Code**

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static string Glyph
    {
        get
        {
            return "\xE72E";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I posted to WinUI issue awhile ago but it's still in triage. https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6306